# Integrals of the type $f'(z)/f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, complex-integration

I am having trouble understanding integrals of the form: $$\int_\gamma\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,{\rm d}z$$I am aware that there are problems with the complex logarithm, and we have the formula: $$\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,{\rm d}z = 2\pi i(Z(f,\gamma)-P(f,\gamma)),$$if $\gamma$ is a closed contour, where $Z(f,\gamma)$ is the number os zeros inside $\gamma$ counted with multiplicity, and the same thing for $P(f,\gamma)$ and poles. My trouble is pretty much as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715453/cauchys-argument-principle-trouble-working-simple-contour-integral), but the answers there aren't detailed enough.

I am sure my lack of understanding is conceptual, so I'll put here two or three examples (taken of my head) so you can pinpoint better what I am thinking wrong. I know about residue integration, but that I understand, so I won't use it.

- Say I take $f(z) = z^2-1$, and $\gamma(t) = 2e^{it}$, with $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$. By the formula, I expect the integral to be: $$\oint_\gamma \frac{2z}{z^2-1}\,{\rm d}z = 4\pi i$$ A direct computation gives me: $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{4e^{it}}{4e^{2it}-1}2ie^{it}\,{\rm d}t = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{8ie^{2it}}{4e^{2it}-1}\,{\rm d}t \color{blue}{=} \ln(4e^{2it}-1)\big|_0^{2\pi} \color{red}{=} 0.$$
- Another one: $f(z) = z^2-z-2$, and $\gamma(t) = 5e^{it}$, $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$. Again I expect the integral to be $4\pi i$. But: $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{10e^{it}-1}{25e^{2it}-5e^{it}-2}5ie^{it}\,{\rm d}t \color{blue}{=} \ln(25e^{2it}-5e^{it}-2)\big|_0^{2\pi} \color{red}{=} 0.$$
- In general: $$\int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,{\rm d}z = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f'(re^{it})}{f(re^{it})}ire^{it}\,{\rm d}t \color{blue}{=} \ln(f(re^{it}))\big|_0^{2\pi} \color{red}{=}0$$

Right now I bet you're probably wanting to say that the complex logarithm is multivalued, and that's what's going wrong. This just doesn't cut it for me, because in the red $\color{red}{=}$, I'll keep getting the *same* damn point to evaluate the $\ln$.

And about the argument, in the other question they said something in the lines of breaking the integral into real and imaginary parts, the real parts cancelling, and we only having left something like: $$\arg(f(\gamma(t)))\big|_0^{2\pi},$$ and I know that this must be a multiple of $2\pi$, but I can't see **how** this comes up in the middle of the calculation.

I am terribly confused, the books all start hand-waving, and I don't find similar questions to this one, except the one I linked. Books don't give practical examples of the above situation, and the only one is that trivial $\int_\gamma 1/z \,{\rm d}z$ which does not clarify anything.

> In the above examples, the mistake is in the $\color{blue}{=}$'s or in the $\color{red}{=}$'s? How that $\arg(f(z))\big|_\gamma$ being a multiple of $2\pi$ comes into the calculation? Is there any example?

Comment: Depends how you read what you have written down. In the first example  you are using only the real part of the logarithm for evaluation. It's the arg which comes in here.

Comment: How that logarithm breaks? I don't see **how** the arg goes there.

Comment: The $\ln$ is multi-valued.  This means that when you do the computation $[\ln(\gamma(t))]_a^b$ and $\gamma(a) = \gamma(b)$, it doesn't imply that $\ln(\gamma(a)) = \ln(\gamma(b))$.  That's what multi-valued means - you input the same value, but you get a choice of different outputs.

Comment: Compute your last integral explicitly in the case $f(z) = z$.  You will see that the answer is $2\pi i$.

Comment: Yes, and I know that $\ln(\gamma(a)) = {\rm Arg}(\gamma(a)) + 2\pi n$, for $n \in \Bbb Z$, and $\ln(\gamma(b)) = {\rm Arg}(\gamma(b)) + 2\pi m$, with $m \in \Bbb Z$, with the ${\rm Arg}$s in $\left]-\pi,\pi\right]$. But when I make $$\ln(\gamma(t))\big|_a^b = 2\pi(n-m),$$I can make that value whatever I want, since I can choose $n$ and $m$..

Comment: That example of $f(z) = z$ is too trivial to clarify anything for me..

Comment: Except that what you did only shows that the answer *could* be any number of the form $2\pi i (n-m)$.  But it doesn't tell you it can arbitrarily pick any of them.

Comment: So how can I choose the little bastards? haha

Comment: With the last example, you could try $f(z) = z^n$ and you can explicitly compute that the answer is $2\pi i n$.  But in general, you need to count the poles and zeroes by multiplicity and winding number and use that formula you wrote at the top.  Look, you need to take a course on complex variables, or read a book on the subject.  To explain everything is just too much to put into a few comments here.

Comment: I understand, thanks. Well, I took a course on complex variables last semester, but we covered integrals very fast and very in the end of the course. I'm on vacation now trying to understand it. What I get from your last comment is: that approach I tried to do in the three examples above is doomed to fail. Say I want to find the number of zeros and poles of a function *by computing the integral*.. it's a no-go? Thanks for the help so far (and I understand if you'd rather not continue the discussion here, no hard feelings)

Comment: OK, in your first example, the function has two zeros at $\pm 1$, each of multiplicity 1.  The curve goes around each zero once.  So the answer is $4\pi i$.  The second example is very similar - the curve is a counterclockwise curve of radius 5 centered at 0 going around once.  So you just need to compute the zeros (using the quadratic formula) and check that they both have absolute value less than 5.

Comment: In other words, your approach of computing the integral, and then reverse engineering the number of zeros is generally a no-go.  (Although you could compute the integral numerically, divide by $2\pi i$, and then see to which integer you are nearest.)

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I have no problem actually finding zeroes and poles, etc. And I know how to integrate a few things using the residue theorem. My problem was specifically with these integrals which end up having $\ln$ appearing. I guess tackling them directly it's really hopeless then :P